# Slow MS Access Sub Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have three tables in Access:

```
employees
----------------------------------
id (pk),name

times
----------------------
id (pk),employee_id,event_time

time_notes
----------------------
id (pk),time_id,note
```

I want to get the record for each employee record from the times table with an event_time immediately prior to some time.  Doing that is simple enough with this:

```
    select employees.id, employees.name, 
(select top 1 times.id from times where times.employee_id=employees.id and times.event_time<=#2018-01-30 14:21:48# ORDER BY times.event_time DESC) as time_id 
from employees
```

However, I also want to get some indication of whether there's a matching record in the time_notes table:

```
select employees.id, employees.name, 
(select top 1 time_notes.id from time_notes where time_notes.time_id=(select top 1 times.id from times where times.employee_id=employees.id and times.event_time<=#2018-01-30 14:21:48# ORDER BY times.event_time DESC)) as time_note_present,
(select top 1 times.id from times where times.employee_id=employees.id and times.event_time<=#2018-01-30 14:21:48# ORDER BY times.event_time DESC) as last_time_id 
from employees
```

This does work but it's SOOOOO SLOW.  We're talking 10 seconds or more if there's 100 records in the employee table.  The problem is peculiar to Access as I can't use the last_time_id result of the other sub-query like I can in MySQL or SQL Server.

I am looking for tips on how to speed this up.  Either a different query, indexes.  Something.

Comment: This question may be more suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks. Do I just post it up there too or can this be moved?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if something like this would work for you?

```
SELECT 
    employees.id, 
    employees.name, 
    time_notes.id AS time_note_present,
    times.id AS last_time_id
FROM 
    (
        employees LEFT JOIN 
        (
            times INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT times.employee_id AS lt_employee_id, max(times.event_time) AS lt_event_time
                FROM times
                WHERE times.event_time <= #2018-01-30 14:21:48#
                GROUP BY times.employee_id
            )  
            AS last_times 
            ON times.event_time = last_times.lt_event_time AND times.employee_id = last_times.lt_employee_id
        ) 
        ON employees.id = times.employee_id
    )
    LEFT JOIN time_notes ON times.id = time_notes.time_id;
```

(Completely untested and may contain typos)

Comment: Your SQL kung fu is better than mine.  I see what you're trying to do but Access doesn't.  It responds with the rather unhelpful "JOIN expression not supported".

Comment: @nemmy, I updated my code shortly after posting - have you tried the updated version?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your query is running multiple correlated subqueries even a nested one in a `WHERE` clause. Correlated queries calculate a value separately for each row, corresponding to outer query.

Similar to @LeeMac, simply join all your tables to an aggregate query for the max *event_time* grouped by *employee_id* which will run **once** across all rows. Below *times* is the base`FROM` table joined to the aggregate query, *employees*, and *time_notes* tables:

```
select e.id, e.name, t.event_time, n.note
from ((times t
inner join 
   (select sub.employee_id, max(sub.event_time) as max_event_time
    from times sub
    where sub.event_time <= #2018-01-30 14:21:48#
    group by sub.employee_id
   ) as agg_qry
on t.employee_id = agg_qry.employee_id and t.event_time = agg_qry.max_event_time)

inner join employees e
on e.id = t.employee_id)

left join time_notes n
on n.time_id = t.id
```

Comment: Curious OP, @nemmy, did you attempt above query? Any errors?